# What are the differential equations that model a self-propagating gravitational wave in space-time?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, gravitational-waves, differential-equations, linearized-theory

Light is a self-propagating wave, but it's very complicated.

Imagine, if you will, a wave in space-time that by assumption was self-propagating like light, except that it was a [gravitational wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave).

What are the differential equations and boundary conditions that would govern the transfer of a wave between two absorption points?

I'm familiar with differential equations, but not the specifics of differential geometry that might better address this.

Answer (score 6):

Wave equation for Gravitational wave(GW) comes from Einstein field equation in general relativity, with linearized approximation. Einstein equation is originally non-linear DE, but we can approximate it become linear. Set metric:

$$g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}, \; |h_{\mu\nu}| \ll 1$$

Calculate Christoffel symbol, Riemann curvature tensor, and so on. These things consist of many derivative terms of metric, but we only consider 1st-order $\mathcal{O}(h_{\mu\nu})$ terms. Then, Einstein equation will be reduced in linear DE. (I skip many details of process to derive wave equation from Einstein equation)

Small perturbation of metric $h_{\mu\nu}$ can be decomposed in each component $h_{00}, \; h_{0i}, \; h_{ij}$. For simplicity, we will use only spatial part with transverse gauge. Also, assume it is vacuum case. Then, DE is reduced like that:

$$\square h_{\mu\nu} = 0 $$

where $h_{\mu\nu}$ satisfies $h_{0 \nu} = 0$ (purely spatial), $ \eta^{\mu\nu} h_{\mu\nu} = 0$ (tracelss), $\partial_{\mu} h^{\mu\nu} = 0$ (transverse).

General solution of this DE is plane wave.

$$h_{\mu\nu} = C_{\mu\nu} e^{i k_{\sigma} x^{\sigma}}$$

and $C_{\mu \nu}$ will have such form. (assume propagating to $z$ direction)

$$C_{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & C_1 & C_2 & 0 \\
0 & C_2 & -C_1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} $$

If we recover inhomogenous term in RHS,

$$\square h_{\mu\nu} \simeq 8 \pi G T_{\mu\nu} $$

then solution can be expressed with Green function and retarded time.

$$h_{\mu\nu}(t, \vec{x}) \simeq 8 \pi G \int \frac{1}{4\pi |\vec{x}-\vec{y}|} T_{\mu\nu}(t',\vec{y}) d^3 y $$

where $t = t' + |\vec{x}-\vec{y}|$

$\textbf{Edit}$

Here is a brief process of linearization:

Terms in Christoffel symbol are replaced to $h_{\mu\nu}$ instead of $g_{\mu\nu}$.

$$\Gamma^{\rho} _{\mu \nu} =  \frac{1}{2} \eta^{\rho \lambda} (\partial_{\mu} h_{\nu \lambda} + \partial_{\nu} h_{\mu \lambda} - \partial_{\lambda} h_{\mu\nu}  ) $$

$O((h_{\mu\nu})^2)$ order terms in Riemann curvature tensor are neglected. Also, Ricci tensor $R_{\mu\nu}$ and Ricci scalar $R$ have linear forms, too.

$$R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} = \eta_{\mu\lambda} \partial_{[\rho,} \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\sigma],\nu} + O((h_{\mu\nu})^2)  $$

Now, put them all to Einstein equation, then linearized form is yieleded.

$$ R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2} Rg_{\mu\nu}
= 8\pi G T_{\mu\nu} $$

$$\frac{1}{2} (\partial_{\sigma}\partial_{(\nu,} h^{\sigma} \; _{\mu)} -\partial_{\mu} \partial_{\nu} h - \square h_{\mu\nu} - \eta_{\mu\nu} \partial_{\rho}\partial_{\sigma} h^{\rho \lambda} + \eta_{\mu\nu} \square h   )  = 8\pi G T_{\mu\nu}  $$

Some redudant terms can be removed with transverse gauge assumption.

Comment: I appreciate your work, but I was not looking to linearize the differential system.

Comment: @StackQuest the term waves, refers to solution of wave equations. In other words we understand gravitational waves as waves precisely because of this approximation. Wave-like solutions of nonlinear differential equations are generally (in essence) called solitons.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know "what" I'm linearizing if I'm not given the original differential equations, it leaves me in the dark a bit. If this post included the original differential equations, then showed how their linearization resulted from those original equations, I would appreciate that.

Comment: The original differential equations are precisely Einstein's field equations.

Comment: @StackQuest I attached brief process of derivation of linearized DE from original Einstein equation. In my edit, final two equations are Einstein equation, and linearized version, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Light as a self-propagating wave in vacuum is governed by the free Maxwell equations:
$$\nabla^aF_{ab}=0$$The electric and magnetic fields which shows the oscillatory behavior are actually the components of the Maxwell tensor $F_{ab}$. One could ask - [what are the analogues of $F_{ab}$ in GR?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/665273/what-are-the-analogues-of-f-mu-nu-in-general-relativity/665326#665326) Note that one can express the vacuum Einstein's field equations $R_{ab}=0$ as divergence of Weyl tensor:
$$\nabla^aC_{abcd}=0$$ which looks quite similar to free Maxwell equations. There are other representations of these vacuum equations - for instance in 2-spinor formalism one can define a free zero rest mass (z.r.m.) field equation for a general spin n/2, for example see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/691703/linearization-of-the-klein-gordon-equation-and-decoupling-of-spinors/691870#691870). However, unlike free Maxwell equation, the vacuum Einstein's equations $\nabla^aC_{abcd}=0$ are not exactly linear in $C_{abcd}$, since both the connection $\nabla^a$ and $C^{abcd}$ depends on metric $g_{ab}$. Solutions of such non-linear differential equations are indeed hard to find. Some solutions for exact plane waves and spherical waves have been discussed [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/100727?origin=JSTOR-pdf&seq=1), [here](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1962.0036) etc. If we are looking at small perturbations on background Minkowski-metric, then we can essentially linearize the vacuum equations as $$\partial^aK_{abcd}=0$$where $K_{abcd}$ is the linearized Riemann curvature and is traceless (like the Weyl curvature). $K_{abcd}$ is invariant under gauge transformation of linearized metric only when we consider perturbations about Minkowski-metric.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in the full non-linear system, then the differential equations you need to solve are just Einstein's equations in vacuum ($R_{\mu \nu} = 0$).  You'll probably have to learn some differential geometry to go further than this.  In particular, writing this out in terms of a set of coordinates is a subtle issue, because in the context of differential geometry the [very notion of coordinates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/290906/what-is-really-curved-spacetime-or-simply-the-coordinate-lines) is different than in most other fields of physics.

That said, there has been some work done on exact (non-linearized) plane-wave solutions.  A brief description of one such solution can be found in Sections 35.10–12 of Misner, Thorne, & Wheeler's *Gravitation*.  A more recent review of such solutions can also be found in Chapter 24 of *Exact Solutions of Einstein's Field Equations* by Stephani *et al.*, though you'll definitely need some familiarity with differential geometry to absorb what's in there.