What is the time dilation at escape velocity?
I am a newbie but as far as I understand that there are two sources of time dialations, one due to relativistic speeds and the other is due to gravitational field. If I look at these equations they do look pretty similar and if you solve it for v then you get the escape velocity, which seems not random.

So, you need to match the exact time dilation of earth’s gravitional pull to escape from it.
So, my question is this the cause of escape velocity or something magically occur?

Also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/246133 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39176

This is essentially asking about the coincidence between Newtonian escape velocity and Schwarzschild radius, which has already been asked many times.

OP's question isn't about black holes or the Schwarzschild radius. Voting to reopen.

In what way do they look similar? That they both contain factors involving $\sqrt{1-x}$ (albeit one is a multiplier and the other a divisor)?

@EricSmith The Schwarzschild radius is right there in the expression. At no point did I say anything about black holes. The Schwarzschild radius isn't only defined for black holes.

The Schwarzschild radius is there in one of the equations, but (a) it's not clear OP is aware of that, and (b) the OP's question is explicitly about the connection between kinematic and gravitational time dilation. This is related indirectly to the Schwarzschild radius but none of the linked questions address that, and it's not obvious to the beginning student.

Hey I finally managed to understand what you mean:
If you solve the lover equation for v, you get the escape velocity in a such situation where the t and the t' in the lower equation describe a gravitational time dilation. (The ' seems to be missing)

Yeah, and I don’t know why but I feel like this is wrong and that the two dilations should not be added. If you were to move with escape velocity on earth (~11km/h), does the time slow down 2*gravitational dilation of earth?

In the above situation, observed on earth, there is kinetic time dilation. Observed by an observer that has escaped earth, there is kinetic and gravitational time dilation, and those happen to be the same size, and those should be multiplied to get the total time dilation.

Light that is sent up redshifts.
redshift factor = energy factor (because E=hf)
redshift factor = time dilation factor (obviously)
Solving the above system of equations we get:
time dilation factor = energy factor
In the above time dilation meant gravitational time dilation.
Now let us show that:
kinetic time dilation factor = energy factor
$E=\gamma mc^2$
$ t=\gamma t'$
Yes, the factor is $\gamma$
So now we understand that:
kinetic time dilation  factor = ratio of energies
and
gravitational time dilation factor = ratio of energies
Oh yes, escape velocity is ratio of energies too:
kinetic energy  / mass
